# Temporary DNS / Internet outages in ECS containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

App is running on ECS and it processes SQS messages in some intervals. 2-3 times a day we are seeing errors originated in AWS SQS SDK with code EAI_AGAIN. Generally it looks like few times a day there is DNS / Internet outage in ECS containers for some reason. It works again few seconds after error occurs so it lasts just few seconds I suspect.

From ECS logs / events it seems that containers are not restarting / stopped / starting during time when those errors occur.

My question is where should I look for a cause of this behaviour? Our VPC config is quite complicated, generally EC2 instances (on which ECS cluster operates) are in a private network (not visible from outside). However service running on ECS only polls SQS and processes tasks.

Maybe someone encountered similar issues on AWS?

Note: it is not related to SQS service - other services which connect to RDS / external APIs and so on also report similar errors. So this must be some DNS / Internet level issue I guess.

---

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh && \
    apk add --no-cache -t build-dependencies make gcc g++ python libtool autoconf automake
COPY package.json /app
COPY yarn.lock /app
RUN \
    mkdir -p /aws && \
    apk -Uuv add groff less python py-pip && \
    pip install awscli && \
    apk --purge -v del py-pip && \
    rm /var/cache/apk/*
RUN yarn
COPY . /app
```

---

Here is exact error:

```
SQS receive message failed: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443
```

Comment: What type of application are you running? NodeJS app?

Comment: Yes, Node.js app inside docker. I updated question with Dockerfile I use.

Comment: I have similar issue going on but it appears to do something with docker itself and not ECS. I remember this issue typically appears when DNS server hosted over VPN. how about in your case?. Where does your DNS server hosted?. With VPC or outside VPC?

Comment: Yes DNS server is outside of VPC and is accessed over VPN. Do you think it might be caused by this setup? Any solutions?

Comment: Apologies for late reply. Unfortunately, there is no clean solution as the issue for me it is very rare and intermittent only and also I cannot move my DNS server into VPC. I would suggest to set DNS host for your container images as well instead of relying on underlying EC2 host DNS settings. Let me know if this helps.